# How to change ng2 smart table column width?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

This is a sample of my three columns. I want to customize the width sizes.

```
resetPassword: {
    title: this.gridTittle["ResetPassword"],
    type: 'custom',
    renderComponent: UserPasswordResetComponent,
    filter: false
},
userName: {
    title: this.gridTittle["UserName"],
},
roleTypeDescription: {
    title: this.gridTittle["UserType"],
    type: 'text',
    filter: false
},
```

Comment: https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation  : width: '20px'

Comment: You can use the width property. `width:'10px'` or `width:'10%'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the width property. As the [documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation), *"column width example: '20px', '20%'"*. In your code:

```
resetPassword: {
    title: this.gridTittle["ResetPassword"],
    type: 'custom',
    renderComponent: UserPasswordResetComponent,
    filter: false,
    width: 25%
},
userName: {
    title: this.gridTittle["UserName"],
    width: 25%
},
roleTypeDescription: {
    title: this.gridTittle["UserType"],
    type: 'text',
    filter: false,
    width: 50%
},
```

Comment: should have single qoute in your width percent

Answer (score 0):

Important >> this value of **widht** between quotation marks

```
columns: {
      id: {
        title: '#',
        type: 'string',
        sortDirection: 'desc',
        width: '30px'
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Nome',
        type: 'string',
      },
      lastName: {
        title: 'Sobrenome',
        type: 'string',
      },
      username: {
        title: 'Usuário',
        type: 'string',
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make it work with the column attribute.

My solution is:

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep .yourColumnName .ng2-smart-title {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

or

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep .ng2-smart-title {
    min-width: 150px;
  }
}
```

You have a thread [here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/134) with it